# Creating custom msg and srv files failed without err message

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I am using Windows 10 as my operating system, and I am following the ROS2 humble tutorial on creating custom msg and srv files:

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html

I have edited the CMakeLists.txt and the package.xml file. However, when I built the tutorial_interfaces, it failed without any error message. Did I miss any step? Thanks very much.

The contents of the files and the steps for building are as follows:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(tutorial_interfaces)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/Num.msg"
  "msg/Sphere.msg"
  "srv/AddThreeInts.srv"
  DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs # Add packages that above messages depend on, in this case geometry_msgs for Sphere.msg
)

ament_package()
```

package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>tutorial_interfaces</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="user@todo.todo">user</maintainer>
  <license>Apache-2.0</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <depend>geometry_msgs</depend>
  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  
  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

the steps for building:

```
c:\dev\ros2_ws>call C:\dev\ros2_humble\local_setup.bat
"[rti_connext_dds_cmake_module][warning] RTI Connext DDS environment script not found (\resource\scripts\rtisetenv_x64Win64VS2017.bat). RTI Connext DDS will not be available at runtime, unless you already configured PATH manually."

c:\dev\ros2_ws>colcon build --merge-install --packages-select tutorial_interfaces
Starting >>> tutorial_interfaces
--- stderr: tutorial_interfaces
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/rosidl_generator_py_generate_interfaces.cmake:20 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
  are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_execute_extensions.cmake:48 (include)
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:286 (ament_execute_extensions)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/python_cmake_module/cmake/Modules/FindPythonExtra.cmake:52 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
  are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/rosidl_generator_py_generate_interfaces.cmake:23 (find_package)
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_execute_extensions.cmake:48 (include)
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:286 (ament_execute_extensions)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/python_cmake_module/cmake/Modules/FindPythonExtra.cmake:140 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
  are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/rosidl_generator_py_generate_interfaces.cmake:23 (find_package)
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_execute_extensions.cmake:48 (include)
  C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:286 (ament_execute_extensions)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

---
Failed   <<< tutorial_interfaces [8.59s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [9.14s]
  1 package failed: tutorial_interfaces
  1 package had stderr output: tutorial_interfaces

c:\dev\ros2_ws>
```

---

**2023/12/28 update:**

Thanks for ExSystem's suggestion very much.
I found the following error message in the "stdout_stderr.log" file:

```
File "C:\dev\ros2_humble\Lib\site-packages\rosidl_parser\parser.py", line 20, in <module>
      from lark import Lark
ModulenotfoundError No module named 'Lark'
```

Then I followed the solution provided in this [issue](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/issues/183) by using the 'pip3 install lark' command to install the Lark module.

After successfully installing the Lark module and rebooting my computer, I checked its installation status with the following command:

```
c:\dev\ros2_ws>pip3 install lark

Requirement already satisfied: lark in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (1.1.8)
```

Despite installing the Lark module, the building process for the "tutorial_interfaces" continued to fail, and I encountered the same error message in the stdout_stderr.log file.

Additionally, I ensured that before rebuilding "tutorial_interfaces", I deleted the 'build', 'install', and 'log' folders in the workspace.

Could the method used for solving the err message be incorrect? Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the logs for the real reason of the building failure.
These output just showed some (first generated) warnings and may not be the actual reason of the failure (usually happened at the end).

Check this log file may be helpful:

```
<WORKSPACE DIR>\log\build_<DATE TIME OF THE BUILD>\<PROJECT NAME>\stdout_stderr.log
```

Mine output is similar to you, and I checked the log file: the real reason is I am using a ARM64 architecture computer, so it does not match the architecture what ROS2 wanted.

And for non-English users, It will be easy if you change your Windows GUI language into English and make sure you have installed English language pack for Visual Studio before trying to build a project, or you might encounter those error messages being incorrectly encoded in your log file that you can not understand. It seems the building system can not properly deal with different encodings of the log messages generated.